# How to addEventListener to every element of a class

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to add a click and mouseout event listener to every image on a portfolio website without having to use IDs.

I did a test of my code with an id and it works, so the error has something to do with calling the class name or the for loop. The class is actually "`flex-image`" in my HTML/CSS but I converted to camel case in the Javascript. I do not want to use any frameworks, just JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("test").style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById("test").style.height = "500px";
document.getElementById("test").style.width = "500px";
document.getElementById("test").style.transition = "1s";
});

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
document.getElementById("test").style.opacity = ".5";
document.getElementById("test").style.height = "250px";
document.getElementById("test").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("test").style.transition = "1s";
});
```

This test code grabs the first image by id and that IS working.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('flexImage');
for (let i=0; i<images.length, i++){
  images[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   images[i].style.height = "500px";
   images[i].style.width = "500px";
   images[i].style.opacity = "1";
   images[i].style.transition = "1s";
  })

  images[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    images[i].style.height = "250px";
    images[i].style.width = "250px";
    images[i].style.opacity = ".5";
    images[i].style.transition = "1s";
  })
}
```

This section is what I wrote to grab all the elements in the class and that is NOT working. There is no response when I click or mouseout on the images. The code is basically identical aside from the sections referring to the array of class elements.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Instead of doing `images[i].style.height = "500px";` to access its properties, do `this.style.height = "500px";`

Comment: `flex-image` is not `'flexImage'`

Comment: Don't change class name to _camelCase_, use it as is.

Comment: FYI, it is only when one access element properties with javascript one need to use _camelCase_, not when accessing property _values_.

Comment: Your code should work. Please confirm that your images object have a collection of image elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I did make the changes to the class name and changed images[i] to this to access the properties, however it is still not responding to the script. Here is a link to a codepen with the HTML, CSS and JavaScript: https://codepen.io/ceceliacreates/pen/daVGqe

Comment: You have a typo in your `for (let i=0; i<images.length, i++){`, where there is a comma instead of a semicolon after _images.length_ ... should be `for (let i=0; i<images.length; i++){`